# Bit shifting with leading 1

Tags: c++, bit, bit-shift

When I use the >> bitwise operator on 1000 in c++ it gives this result: 1100. I want the result to be 0100. When the 1 is in any other position this is exactly what happens, but with a leading 1 it goes wrong. Why is that and how can it be avoided?

Comment: what data type is your variable holding `1000`?

Comment: Right shifting on **signed numbers** can do that.  Change your type to **unsigned int**.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift

Comment: Is this a hexadecimal number? A binary number? The integer literal "1000" (decimal 1000) should only be interpreted as negative if assigned to an 8-bit signed char or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you describe is coherent with what happens on *some* platforms when right-shifting a signed integer with the high bit set (so, negative values).

In this case, on many platforms compilers will emit code to perform an [*arithmetic* shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift), which propagates the sign bit; this, on platforms with 2's complement representation for negative integers (= virtually every current platform) has the effect of giving the "`x >> i` = floor(x/2<sup>i</sup>)" behavior even on negative values. Notice that this is not contractual - as far as the C++ standard is concerned, shifting negative integers in implementation-defined behavior, so any compiler is free to implement different semantics for it<sup>1</sup>.

To come to your question, to obtain the "regular" shift behavior (generally called "logical shift") you have to make sure to work on `unsigned` integers. This can be obtained either making sure that the variable you are shifting is of unsigned type (e.g. `unsigned int`) or, if it's a literal, by putting an `U` suffix to it (e.g. `1` is an `int`, `1U` is an `unsigned int`).

If the data you have is of a signed type (e.g. `int`) you may cast it to the corresponding `unsigned` type before shifting without risks (conversion from a signed int to an unsigned one is well-defined by the standard, and doesn't change the bit values on 2's complement machines).

---

1. Historically, this comes from the fact that C strove to support even machines that didn't have "cheap" arithmetic shift functionality at hardware level and/or didn't use 2's complement representation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, when right shifting on a signed int, it is implementation defined whether you will get 1s or 0s. In your case, because the left most bit in 1000 is a 1, the "replacement bits" are also 1. Assuming you must work with signed ints, in order to get rid of it, you can apply a bitmask.

Comment: Right shifting on a negative signed int is implementation defined. Right shifting on a positive signed int is well defined.